# use "no cache" but input filter seems to be cached in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, caching, input-formats

I am trying to display a add to cart button and it only rarely works. It seems to work when the cache is cleared and then not work. I have added the no cache option but this doesn't seem to do anything:

```
function ss_cg_filters_filter($op, $delta = 0, $format = -1, $text = '') {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
      return array(
        0 => t('Display Add to Cart button based on it\'s node/ID number.'),
      ); 
    case 'no cache':
          return TRUE;
    case 'description':
          return t('This will replace [add-cart:435] into the button (complete form).');
    case 'process':
          return preg_replace_callback('`\[ *?add-cart: *?(\d+)\ *?]`i', '_ss_cg_filter_add_cart_button', $text);
        default:
          return $text;
    default:
      return $text;
  }
}
function _ss_cg_filter_add_cart_button($matches) {
  $product_node = node_load((int) $matches[1]);
  return theme('uc_product_add_to_cart', $product_node);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? is there a bug with caching?

Comment: you might be using [hook_filter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_filter/6) wrong. [php_filter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!php!php.module/function/php_filter/6) does what your trying to do.

Comment: You can inspect the DB table `cache_filter` to see whether the filter system's caching the output. If it's not I guess another cache is the culprit: perhaps the page or block?

Comment: @mikeytown2 Thanks for that link I'm going to have to investigate that more. I am trying to make a fool proof way of my client (who loves to tinker) be able to basically add Ubercart "add to cart" links anywhere without messing with the code.